# Android - passing string data from Fragment to Activity using TabLayout, ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to pass few string data from 4 fragments to 1 containing activity. This containing activity is using TabLayout and ViewPager. And I'd like to make string array which is declared in containing activity, filled with these string data from fragments. So I made 4 OnFragmentInteractionListener interface in each fragment, and overrided them in containing activity. But it didn't work. I'm getting numerous errors like this.

```
 --------- beginning of crash
        05-20 04:31:14.572 2495-2495/com.example.jsfish_lt.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.jsfish_lt.test, PID: 2495
        java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
        at android.content.res.XmlBlock.newParser(XmlBlock.java:71)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2797)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2776)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1165)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
        at com.example.jsfish_lt.test.containing.02_Fragment.onCreateView(02_Fragment.java:52)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1332)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2288)
        at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:186)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at com.example.jsfish_lt.test.containing.02_Fragment.onCreateView(02_Fragment.java:52)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1332)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2288)
        at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:186)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at com.example.jsfish_lt.test.containing.02_Fragment.onCreateView(02_Fragment.java:52)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1332)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2288)
        at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:186)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at com.example.jsfish_lt.test.containing.02_Fragment.onCreateView(02_Fragment.java:52)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1332)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2288)
        at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWra
        05-20 04:31:14.596 2495-2505/com.example.jsfish_lt.test I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 6.392ms for cause Background
        05-20 04:31:14.711 2495-2501/com.example.jsfish_lt.test W/art: Suspending all threads took: 26.019ms
        05-20 04:31:14.750 2495-2505/com.example.jsfish_lt.test I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 156819(21MB) AllocSpace objects, 18(61MB) LOS objects, 3% free, 124MB/128MB, paused 596us total 147.945ms
        05-20 04:31:14.801 2495-2495/com.example.jsfish_lt.test D/Error: ERR: exClass=java.lang.StackOverflowError
        05-20 04:31:14.801 2495-2495/com.example.jsfish_lt.test D/Error: ERR: exMsg=stack size 8MB
        05-20 04:31:14.801 2495-2495/com.example.jsfish_lt.test D/Error: ERR: file=XmlBlock.java
        05-20 04:31:14.801 2495-2495/com.example.jsfish_lt.test D/Error: ERR: class=android.content.res.XmlBlock
        05-20 04:31:14.801 2495-2495/com.example.jsfish_lt.test D/Error: ERR: method=newParser line=71
        05-20 04:31:14.852 2495-2495/com.example.jsfish_lt.test D/Error: ERR: stack=java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
        at android.content.res.XmlBlock.newParser(XmlBlock.java:71)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2797)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2776)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1165)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
        at com.example.jsfish_lt.test.containing.02_Fragment.onCreateView(02_Fragment.java:52)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1332)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2288)
        at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:186)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at com.example.jsfish_lt.test.containing.02_Fragment.onCreateView(02_Fragment.java:52)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1332)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2288)
        at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:186)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at com.example.jsfish_lt.test.containing.02_Fragment.onCreateView(02_Fragment.java:52)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1332)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2288)
        at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:186)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at com.example.jsfish_lt.test.containing.02_Fragment.onCreateView(02_Fragment.java:52)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1332)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2288)
        at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
        at android.vie
        05-20 04:31:14.856 2495-2495/com.example.jsfish_lt.test D/Error: ERR: TOTAL BYTES WRITTEN: 11660880
        05-20 04:31:14.856 2495-2495/com.example.jsfish_lt.test E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 11660972)
        05-20 04:31:14.872 2495-2495/com.example.jsfish_lt.test E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
        android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 11660972 bytes
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:4425)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:90)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
        05-20 04:31:14.872 2495-2495/com.example.jsfish_lt.test I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2495 SIG: 9
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Containing Activity.java

```
package com.example.jsfish_lt.test.containing;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.example.jsfish_lt.test.R;

public class SurveyActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements Survey_01_Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Survey_02_Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Survey_03_Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Survey_04_Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {    

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {
    }    

    public static String surveyResult[] = new String[14];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_survey);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);    
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_survey, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(int fg_id, String string1, String string2, String string3, String string4) {

        switch (fg_id){
            case 1:
                surveyResult[0] = string1;
                surveyResult[1] = string2;
                surveyResult[2] = string3;
                surveyResult[3] = string4;
                break;
            case 3:
                surveyResult[7] = string1;
                surveyResult[8] = string2;
                surveyResult[9] = string3;
                surveyResult[10] = string4;
                break;
        }    
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(int fg_id, String string1, String string2, String string3) {

       switch (fg_id){
            case 2:
                surveyResult[4] = string1;
                surveyResult[5] = string2;
                surveyResult[6] = string3;
                break;
            case 4:
                surveyResult[11] = string1;
                surveyResult[12] = string2;
                surveyResult[13] = string3;
                Log.i("SurveyResult : ", surveyResult.toString());
                break;
        }

    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).

            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return Survey_01_Fragment.newInstance(position+1);
                case 1:
                    return Survey_02_Fragment.newInstance(position+1);
                case 2:
                    return Survey_03_Fragment.newInstance(position+1);
                case 3:
                    return Survey_04_Fragment.newInstance(position+1);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            String title = "";
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    title = "111";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    title = "222";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    title = "333";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    title = "444";
                    break;
            }
            return title;
        }
    }


}
```

Survey_01_Fragment.java

```
package com.example.jsfish_lt.test.containing;    

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.jsfish_lt.test.R;

public class Survey_01_Fragment extends Fragment {
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    private static final String ARG_NICKNAME = "NICKNAME";
    private static final String ARG_AGE = "AGE";
    private static final String ARG_GENDER = "GENDER";
    private static final String ARG_JOB = "JOB";

    private EditText mNicknameView;
    private EditText mAgeView;
    private String mGenderSpinner;
    private String mJobSpinner;

    public Survey_01_Fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static Survey_01_Fragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        Survey_01_Fragment fragment = new Survey_01_Fragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_01, container, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.survey_number, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));

        mNicknameView = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.survey_01_et_nickname);
        mAgeView = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.survey_01_et_age);

        Spinner spGender = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.survey_01_sp_gender);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spGenderAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.gender, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spGenderAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spGender.setAdapter(spGenderAdapter);
        spGender.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                mGenderSpinner = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                mGenderSpinner = "";
            }
        });

        Spinner spJob = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.survey_01_sp_job);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spJobAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.job, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spJobAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spJob.setAdapter(spJobAdapter);
        spJob.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                mJobSpinner = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) { mJobSpinner = ""; }
        });

        Button btPrev = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.survey_01_bt_prev);

        Button btNext = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.survey_01_bt_next);
        btNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               int id = 1;
                if(mListener != null)
                    mListener.onFragmentInteraction(id, mNicknameView.getText().toString(), mAgeView.getText().toString(), mGenderSpinner, mJobSpinner);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(int fg_id, String string1, String string2, String string3, String string4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to use 4 different interfaces rather than a single interface with some parameters in its methods? I don't know, just an idea.

Comment: Actually, I didn't mean that for specific reason...I just looked some tutorial and added that code, I'm not good at using interface :(

Comment: Ok. First I would implement a log at the very beginning of the  onFragmentInteraction  method in the Activity to see whether the method is called properly. I personally find it very easy to troubleshoot that way.

Comment: thank you, I will try your suggestion :)

Comment: @MalithLakshan I tried your suggestion like this.  
    public void onFragmentInteraction(int fg_id, String string1, String string2, String string3, String string4) {

        Log.i("SurveyResult : ", string1); But I can't see any Log in Logcat window :(....

Comment: Make sure  mListener.onFragmentInteraction() is called at btNext onClickListener. Make a log there before calling the interface method to see whether all the parameters you try to pass onto the interface method are valid and existing.

Comment: @MalithLakshan When I just clicked the button that shows containing activity, application is shut down. So I think, any log can't be captured on Logcat.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SurveyActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements Survey_01_Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Survey_02_Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Survey_03_Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Survey_04_Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {    

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

private ViewPager mViewPager;

public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {
}    

public static String surveyResult[] = new String[14];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_survey);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);    
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_survey, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(int fg_id, String string1, String string2, String string3, String string4) {

    switch (fg_id){
        case 1:
            surveyResult[0] = string1;
            surveyResult[1] = string2;
            surveyResult[2] = string3;
            surveyResult[3] = string4;
            break;
        case 3:
            surveyResult[7] = string1;
            surveyResult[8] = string2;
            surveyResult[9] = string3;
            surveyResult[10] = string4;
            break;
    }    
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(int fg_id, String string1, String string2, String string3) {

   switch (fg_id){
        case 2:
            surveyResult[4] = string1;
            surveyResult[5] = string2;
            surveyResult[6] = string3;
            break;
        case 4:
            surveyResult[11] = string1;
            surveyResult[12] = string2;
            surveyResult[13] = string3;
            Log.i("SurveyResult : ", surveyResult.toString());
            break;
    }

}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return 01_Fragment.newInstance(position+1);
            case 1:
                return 02_Fragment.newInstance(position+1);
            case 2:
                return 03_Fragment.newInstance(position+1);
            case 3:
                return 04_Fragment.newInstance(position+1);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String title = "";
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                title = "111";
                break;
            case 1:
                title = "222";
                break;
            case 2:
                title = "333";
                break;
            case 3:
                title = "444";
                break;
        }
        return title;
    }
}


}



public class Survey_01_Fragment extends Fragment {
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

private static final String ARG_NICKNAME = "NICKNAME";
private static final String ARG_AGE = "AGE";
private static final String ARG_GENDER = "GENDER";
private static final String ARG_JOB = "JOB";

private EditText mNicknameView;
private EditText mAgeView;
private String mGenderSpinner;
private String mJobSpinner;

public Survey_01_basicinfoFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static Survey_01_Fragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
    Survey_01_Fragment fragment = new Survey_01_Fragment ();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question :) Sorry for the confusion. Actually, I renamed file name to ask question..., the real file name is just like you said.

Comment: Thank you, I think I made too many mistakes when I renamed class name for asking question. Again, I'm sorry for confusion, now I fixed all of them.